# Asynchronously modify a local variable in Python

Tags: python

I have a function that runs in a different thread and when an event is raised it calls a function that is given to it as an argument like so:

```
import keyboard

def func(arg):
    pass

keyboard.on_press(func)
```

This (on_press) function also passes an argument to (func).

```
import keyboard


def func(arg):
    ...


def func2(a):
    ...


def func3(a):
    ...


def func4(a):
    ...


def main():
   keyboard.on_press(func)
   while True:
        pos = func2(randint(10))
        check = True
        while check:
            pos = func3(pos)
            check = func4(pos)

main()
```

In the above example I want to pass (pos) to (func) as well as the argument (on_press) passes to (func) but I don't know how.
I can't call (on_press) multiple times.
My goal is for (func) to be able to modify (pos) when an event is raised asynchronously.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand exactly your problem. Try to explain it better, please. To share a value between threads, just make them accessible in all methods (global variable or even better a class). If the value is sensitive to race conditions (i.e. different keypresses can yield different values, and the order is critical in your app), you'll have to introduce a mutex (Lock).

Comment: I didn't want to make the variable global because I had a lot of variables with the same name in other functions(as arguments) and i thought that would mess things up but it doesn't.Thanks for the response. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share a value between threads, just make them accessible in all methods (global variable or even better a class).

```py
import keyboard

pos = randint(10)

def func():
   global pos
   ...


def func2():
   global pos
   ...


def func3():
   global pos
   ...


def func4():
   global pos
   ...


def main():
   global pos
   keyboard.on_press(func)
   while True:
        pos = func2()
        check = True
        while check:
            pos = func3(pos)
            check = func4(pos)

main()
```

If the value is sensitive to race conditions (i.e. different keypresses can yield different values, and the order is critical in your app), you'll have to introduce a mutex (Lock).

```py
from threading import Lock

class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.mutex = Lock()
        self.pos = randint(10)
    
    def func():
        with self.mutex:
            print(self.pos)
        ...
    
    def func2():
        with self.mutex:
            print(self.pos)
        ...

    def func3():
        with self.mutex:
            print(self.pos)
        ...

    def func4():
        with self.mutex:
            print(self.pos)
        ...

    def main():
        keyboard.on_press(func)
        while True:
            with self.mutex:
                self.pos = self.func2()
            check = True
            while check:
                with self.mutex:
                    self.pos = self.func3()
                check = self.func4()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyClass().main()
```